# Ellipse drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, ellipse

I'm trying to draw an ellipse using only glVertex2i function, I'm letting the user to enter 2 foci points and a point on the ellipse. My question is: how to find the rest of the ellipse points.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mathematical formula, not about issues found when programming a mathematical formula.

Comment: I'd agree with SJuan76, once you've got the axis lengths, a simple DDA would get you a vertex array. So this is just a maths question on how to get axis lengths.

Comment: The question should be moved to the Mathematics community.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html). The steps you have to do are:

1. Transform your coordinate system such that the too foci points lie at `(-c,0)` and `(+c,0)`
2. Compute the semimajor axis as `2*a = r1 + r2` where `r1` resp. `r2` are the distances between the given point and the foci points.
3. Compute the semiminor axis as `b*b = a*a - c*c`
4. Now you can use the simple parametric form `x = a*cos(t)` and `y = b*sin(t)` with `t` ranging from `0` to `2 pi` to create sample points on the ellipse.
5. Transform these points back using the inverse of the transformation from step 1

Comment: I need a C++ function to draw the ellipse with the given points.

Comment: From the given information it should be easy to implement.